# json_encode() automatically converts array into object

Tags: php, json

When I encode an array with `json_encode()` in `PHP`, all gets done right till here, but when I decode it back with `json_decode()`, it gives me `stdClass` Object instead of an Array.
Here is my code:

```
echo $json=json_encode(array('a'=>1,'b'=>2));
echo '<br>';
print_r(json_decode($json));

// and the result of PHP script is :
{"a":1,"b":2}
// stdClass Object ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 )
```

what converts it into object from an array ??

can i pass the json encoded string into url to get data on another page, or there exists any function that can do some url encoding ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. A few seconds spent [reading the manual entry](http://au2.php.net/json_decode) would have saved you the trouble of asking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[json_decode()](https://www.php.net/json_decode) needs an extra parameter to decode to an array.

`json_decode($json, true)`

Comment: can i pass the json encoded string into url to get data on another page, or there exists any function that can do some url encoding ?

Comment: You would like to use it together, it would work like `urlencode((json_decode($json, true))`.

Comment: But, what is a multi-dimensional array of objects is passed? It is converting objects into arrays recursively.